# Access violation when opening form 2th time on Android in Delphi XE7

Tags: android, forms, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

When I open my form for the first time I get no violation, but when I first select a TEdit field and then close the form and then recreate the form and open it I get the Violation.

**Code for creating the form:**

```
procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.actConfigExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  confForm: TConfiguratie;
begin
  confForm := TConfiguratie.Create(nil);
  confForm.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      confForm.DisposeOf;//Also tried confForm.Free;
    end);
end;
```

**I've also tried this for creating the form:**

```
procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.actConfigExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  confForm: TConfiguratie;
begin
  confForm := TConfiguratie.Create(nil);
  try
    confForm.ShowModal(
      procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
      begin
      end);
  finally
    confForm.free;
  end;
end;
```

**Code for Closing the form:**

```
procedure TConfiguratie.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

Because the violation only appears when you click on any TEdit and then close the form I think it has something to do with the virtual keyboard, but i'm not sure. I don't have any methods that use the virtual keyboard itself.

Comment: Try removing FormClose altogether. You are releasing form twice.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, thanks. It looks like it's solved! Strange that on the embarcadero site it says you have to use it.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, this is a case when `DisposeOf()` must not be used. See [ShowModal on Android](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1585) for details.

Comment: @LURD I also found that tutorial of the showModal on Android but in this case it's not correct.

Comment: Could any of what you've observed count as the "unexpected behavior" that [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.ShowModal) warns about when using `ShowModal` on the mobile platforms, where modal dialogs aren't supported?

Comment: @RobKennedy Well no, because i had the same problem on form.show

Comment: @Dalija, see my updated answer. Focused controls are holding a strong reference and this causes the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seemed to be only accuring in Delphi XE7. I am now using Delphi XE8 and don't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

While my suggestions here are as documented, there are still problems with Android and multiple forms. See later in this post.

---

Do not call `DisposeOf()` or `Free` at all. The `FormClose()` and the `caFree` call is the key to make it work.

The documentation how to dispose of a modal dialog has been changed: [Using FireMonkey Modal Dialog Boxes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_FireMonkey_Modal_Dialog_Boxes).

The FireMonkey architects has struggled with this for several versions now, <strike>and finally it works</strike>.

Example from doc how to create a modal dialog:

```
procedure MyCurrentForm.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TMyModalForm;
begin
  // Create an instance of a form.
  dlg := TMyModalForm.Create(nil);

  // Configure the form. For example, give it a display name.
  dlg.Caption := 'My Modal Dialog Box';

  // Show your dialog box and provide an anonymous method that handles the closing of your dialog box.
  dlg.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      // Do something.
    end
  );
end;
```

And to free your modal dialog:

```
procedure TMyModalForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

[image]

---

**Update**

The OP has tried this solution and it does not work as expected.

Looking into QC, there are reports claiming that this does not work as expected on mobile android platforms:

[RSP-9692 Runtime creation of forms in Android](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9692?jql=text%20~%20%22SHOWMODAL%22)
and

[RSP-9665 Access Violation in FMX.Platform.Android SendCMGestureMessage](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9665?jql=text%20~%20%22SHOWMODAL%22).

(You must login to access them).

The latter explains what is happening. When the modal form is destroyed, it is possible that FFocusedControl points to a destroyed control. When ARC is trying to release FFocusedControl this will cause a segmentation fault. FFocusedControl must be declared [weak]. See the RSP-9665 for more details.

There is also [QC-126524 [Android] Open/Close/Free sub form multiple times may cause crash on Android Platform when removing Focus from TEdit](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=126524) reporting the same thing and closed as resolved in XE7. This apparently not true.

Comment: I've also tried this but I still got the error this way. So I guess @DalijaPrasnikar way is the correct way.

Comment: Are you sure you removed the DisposeOf() call? It must not be there at all.

Comment: yes i've removed it. Strange thing is that I don't have this problem on other forms though.

Comment: And don't forget to set the modal dialog `OnClose` event to `FormClose`.

Comment: Ow yes, ofcourse I did that too. I thought you meant something else.

Comment: Then I'm out of suggestions. I can only say that calling DisposeOf will get you into trouble.

Comment: That link about the TEdit seems to be the problem to me. Thanks for the link! Seems like it's not resolved in XE7.

Answer (score 0):

Embarcadero [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.ShowModal) regarding FMX ShowModal and mobile platforms says

Caution: Modal dialog boxes are not supported in Android apps. Instead of calling ShowModal, you should call Show, and have the form return and call your event. We recommend that you not use modal dialogs on either of the mobile platforms (iOS and Android) because unexpected behavior can result. Not using modal dialogs eliminates potential problems in debugging and supporting your mobile apps.

Comment: ShowModal calls Show internally. So there is nothing blocking in the buttonclick method. Any code after the ShowModal call will be executed before the anonymous method.